# writing excel formula for each row in a column

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have data from website that writing to excel every time program run. I need to have formula in few columns using the data in certain cells.
Below is my code and I have manually added values in cells for this example.
I need formulas in column B, Column D and Column F.
Column B should be Sum of A2-A1
Column D should be Sum of C2-C1
Column F should be sum of B1/D1

After writing the row , I need to do formulas for all the rows in columns B, D, F.
How can I insert formula using python? Can someone help.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
path = r"C:/folder/file.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(path)

sheet = wb[sheet_name]

row = sheet.max_row + 1
sheet.cell(row=row, column=1, value="10")  # => column A
sheet.cell(row=row, column=2, value="20")   # => column C
sheet.cell(row=row, column=3, value="100")  # => column E
```

Comment: To insert formula you can use something like this `value="=A2-A1"`

Comment: I have 100s of rows how can I do for all rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
path = r"c:/Temp/file.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(path)

sheet_name = "Sheet1"
sheet = wb[sheet_name]

for row in range(1, 101): # loop over 100 first rows
    sheet.cell(row=row, column=1, value=10)  # => column A
    sheet.cell(row=row, column=3, value=20)   # => column C
    sheet.cell(row=row, column=5, value=100)  # => column E

    # make the formulae
    # I did not understand the meaning of the formulas without sample data
    # and examples, so I tried to do it literally as it was written,
    # with correction for line offset
    sheet.cell(row=row+1, column=2, value=f'=SUM(A{row+1}-A{row})')
    sheet.cell(row=row+1, column=4, value=f'=SUM(C{row+1}-C{row})')
    sheet.cell(row=row+1, column=6, value=f'=IFERROR(SUM(B{row}/D{row}),"-")')

wb.save(path)
wb.close
```